# VS 2015 keeps locking my C# Win Form Application files after first run

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, locking

I have the following issue and hope that someone might help me to get it sorted.

Every time I run my C# Win Forms application for the first time after starting up VS 2015, and stopping the application again, I cannot change any files as they are all locked.

**Steps:**

1. Open/Create new windows form application.
2. Run the application.
3. Close the application.
4. Try to edit anything in your project (fails with the following error: The file C:\Users***\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.Designer.cs cannot be modified at this time.

[[image]

I can see on the Form tab that it shows a lock.

[[image]

At the moment the only way I can get past this is to close VS and open it again every time I want to make changes to my project.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

NO, if this is the case then go ahead and check in `Task Manager` for a process called `devenv.exe`. there will be an already existing/running process present which is blocking/locking your project files. In other words, not all instances of that process is been ended, else you would haven't seen that red lock button in Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have a solution? Tried killing the devenv.exe process, but that just closes VS.

Comment: @DirkieGertenbach, that's the solution I have and I do kind of same if I face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having to cope with this, I have found that closing and reopening the file clears the lock. Annoying to have to do this, but it does work for me.